# Многократное открытие формы

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Доброго всем времени суток.

Вот код нажатия клавиши, который открывает новую форму

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    Option ^w2 = gcnew Option();
    w2->Show();
}
```

Я заметил, что если много раз потыкать на кнопку, откроется много форм. Как этого избежать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать и прверять значение переменной-флага если `true` то выполнять иначе нет